# Getting changed data from PyQt5 QDialog

Tags: python-3.x, configuration, dialog, pyqt5

I've got a configuration dialog that I'm pre-populating with the existing options, which are stored in `cfg`. When the user clicks "Save" (or equivalent), I need to get the new values from the QLineEdit objects. Except I can't figure that bit out. I've been Googling and testing since yesterday evening, before I came here on bended knee yet again. Here's my dialog code (the form is from Qt Designer, which is why there's no GUI code):

```
class Config(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Config, self).__init__()

        popup = QDialog()
        config_ui = configform()
        config_ui.setupUi(popup)

        config_ui.programver.setText(cfg['config']['programver'])

        if cfg['config']['dummycopy']:
            config_ui.democheck.setChecked(True)

        config_ui.tmdbAPIkey.setText(cfg['config']['TMDB_KEY'])
        config_ui.tvdbAPIkey.setText(cfg['config']['TVDB_KEY'])
        config_ui.tvdbUserkey.setText(cfg['config']['TVDB_USERKEY'])

        theme = cfg['config']['theme']

        if theme == "blue":
            config_ui.bluebutton.setChecked(True)
        elif theme == "yellow":
            config_ui.yellowbutton.setChecked(True)
        elif theme == "light":
            config_ui.lightmetalbutton.setChecked(True)
        elif theme == "dark":
            config_ui.darkmetalbutton.setChecked(True)

        programversion = config_ui.programver.text()

        config_ui.savebutton.clicked.connect(lambda: Config.save(self, programversion))

        popup.exec_()


    def save(self, programversion):
        QDialog.close(self)
        print(programversion)
```

I need some voodoo to get at the changed fields. All I can get now are the original values from when the dialog was brought to life. Is there a trick to this? I can't be the first person to try pre-populating a dialog box. I swear I've tried every combination of button and buttonBox variations available.

I'm thinking maybe there's some way of hiding the dialog, grabbing the data, and then destroying the dialog? That's one working theory, anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share the design of Qt Designer, in addition to the cfg to help you.

Comment: Here's a gist of the config file (read by ConfigParser module), the XML from config.ui, and the generated Python file...  https://gist.github.com/bundito/e6656928dedc61fa45fa2e1b90b18b12

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work in a simple way we use the design of Qt Designer to fill the Dialog, and we connect the cancel button to self.reject () and the save button to the save () slot, in this we save the data and issue self.accept () :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from Ui_config_dialog import Ui_configdialog
import configparser


class Config(QDialog, Ui_configdialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QDialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.cancelbutton.clicked.connect(self.reject)
        self.filename = "joe.conf"
        self.cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
        self.cfg.read(self.filename)
        self.load()

    def load(self):
        self.programver.setText(self.cfg['config']['programver'])
        self.democheck.setChecked(self.cfg.getboolean("config", "dummycopy"))
        self.tmdbAPIkey.setText(self.cfg['config']['TMDB_KEY'])
        self.tvdbAPIkey.setText(self.cfg['config']['TVDB_KEY'])
        self.tvdbUserkey.setText(self.cfg['config']['TVDB_USERKEY'])
        theme = self.cfg['config']['theme']

        self.buttons = {"blue": self.bluebutton, 
                        "yellow": self.yellowbutton,
                        "light": self.lightmetalbutton,
                        "dark": self.darkmetalbutton}

        self.buttons[theme].setChecked(True)
        self.group = QButtonGroup(self)
        self.group.addButton(self.bluebutton)
        self.group.addButton(self.yellowbutton)
        self.group.addButton(self.lightmetalbutton)
        self.group.addButton(self.darkmetalbutton)
        self.savebutton.clicked.connect(self.save)

    def save(self):
        self.cfg['config']['programver'] = self.programver.text()
        self.cfg['config']['dummycopy'] = "True" if self.democheck.isChecked() else "False"
        self.cfg['config']['TMDB_KEY'] = self.tmdbAPIkey.text()
        self.cfg['config']['TVDB_KEY'] = self.tvdbUserkey.text()
        for key, btn in self.buttons.items():
            if btn == self.group.checkedButton():
                 self.cfg['config']['theme'] = key
                 break

        with open(self.filename, 'w') as configfile: 
            self.cfg.write(configfile)
        self.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Config()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get back to the project and get your code implemented. The `save()` function is the magic I was looking for. Thank you. Answer marked as correct!